# Document Library Upload Issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, file-upload

When I click on **New Document** or **Upload**, a window pops up to attach document. When I click OK, it should show me a form to fill out where I get the opportunity to change the file name. But I am not seeing this form. The document uploads and that is it.

Created completely new doc library in 2 sites below and I am seeing this problem in both sites-

```
company.com/sites/site1 

company.com/sites/site2
```

Tried on chrome and IE, and I still see this problem.

The document library was working fine until today, I dunno what changed today and looks like it is affecting all new doc libraries I create. (One existing library is working fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to library settings and in advanced settings, check "Allow management of content types" as yes. This will prompt the form to fill in the columns.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also set any of the columns as required to prompt the form to fill the column values.